# Using TouchesBegan in my TableViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimage, uitableview

Good afternoon,

I would like to tap the profile image (like Facebook app) inside a row in my TableViewController using "TouchesBegan" to display a new ViewController with more information regarding the user. That means going from TableViewController (touch in the image of the TableViewCell) and then go (segue) to another ViewController called "**ProfileViewController**".

When I tried to do that directly in my **TableViewCell** it didn't worked because it's not a ViewController (it's a subclass of TableViewController) so I cannot move to a different ViewController from that.

So, what I'm trying to do now, is create a **TouchesBegan** in the UIImage from my TableViewController, but I get a warning (and followed by a crash) because I use a NSArray to fill the UIImage URL and it seems that I cannot assign a TouchesBegan directly to the image.

Can you help me with more information or some example? Maybe there is something I'm missing because It's my first time trying to do something like that and any help will be appreciated.

Here you are my code:

That's my **TableViewController**:

```
//
//  CarTableViewController.m
//  TableViewStory
//

#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarTableViewCell.h"
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@implementation CarTableViewController

@synthesize carMakes = _carMakes;
@synthesize carModels = _carModels;
@synthesize carImages = _carImages;

@synthesize likes = _likes;
@synthesize comments = _comments;
@synthesize username = _username;
@synthesize refuser = _refuser;
@synthesize profileImage = _profileImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self fetchJson];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Initialize the refresh control.
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    //self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(fetchJson)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_jsonArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    cell.likes.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"likes"];
    cell.comments.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"];
    cell.username.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    cell.refuser.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user_ref"];

    cell.modelLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];

    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];

    [cell.carImage setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagen"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];

    [cell.profileImage setImageWithURL:imageURL2
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]
                            options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    return cell;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:_profileImage];

    if (pt.x>=0 && pt.x<=100 && pt.y>=0 && pt.y<=100)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ID" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"image not touched");
    }
}

/*
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        CarDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                               initWithObjects:
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"date"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"imagen"],
                                               nil];
    }
}
*/

-(void)fetchJson {

    self.carModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.carMakes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.carImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.likes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.comments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSError *error;
        [_jsonArray removeAllObjects];
        _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                      error:&error];


            for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
            {
                NSDictionary * jsonObject = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* imagen = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"imagen"];
                [_carImages addObject:imagen];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject2 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* user = [jsonObject2 objectForKey:@"user"];
                [_carMakes addObject:user];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject3 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* date = [jsonObject3 objectForKey:@"date"];
                [_carModels addObject:date];
            }
         NSLog(@"carModels ==> %@", _jsonArray);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            {
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
            }});

        }
    );
}



@end
```

And that's my TableViewController.h

```
//
//  CarTableViewController.h
//  TableViewStory
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CarTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *carImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *carMakes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *carModels;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *likes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *comments;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *refuser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *profileImage;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jsonArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImage *touchImageVIew;

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the image acts like a button, you should use a UIButton instead and set the background image. With the UIButton you can set and perform a segue, there is no need to use touchesBegan:: and check for coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. How can I put a button inside my UIImage?

Comment: You got me wrong. You don't put a button inside your UIImageView, you replace your UIImageView with a UIButton. So instead of setting a UIImage as the source for the UIImageView, you set the backgroundImage property of the UIButton. I will post an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your UIImageView should act like a button, you should make it a UIButton instead of a UIImageView. With an UIButton you can set a segue in the Interface Builder. Here's an example of the UITableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let dataSource = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource.addObject(UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!)
        dataSource.addObject(UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableviewcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

        let image = dataSource.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as UIImage
        cell.button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "pushtodetail" {
            println("performing segue from a button in a cell")
        }
    }


}
```